# How to validate a number between a range in laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I want to validate the percentage of my loan that needs to be between 1 to 100, but I can't. I read the laravel documentation about the lte and gte but it was not supported in laravel 5.4. here I tried like this but no luck

```
'percentage' => 'required|in:1,100',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add `between` clause,

```
'percentage'=>'required|integer|between:1,100',
```

Should do it as per [Laravel 5.4 doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-between).

As your field is percentage so there will be float values. For that, you can use,

```
'percentage'=>'required|numeric|between:0,100'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
'percentage' => 'required|integer|between:1,100'
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.